# Как создать эффект "пролетающей" прокрутки?

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия, протягивания и отпускания левой кнопки мыши скролл проскролливался в зависимости от скорости протягивания. То есть после отпускания левой кнопки мыши начинался плавный скролл, который со временем замедлялся бы до полной остановки. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобъем на задачи:

1) Вам нужно узнать скорость мыши;
2) Вам нужно проскроллить с данной скоростью и остановиться.

1. Заводим таймер (setInterval()) на каждые ~30мс. В нем отлавливаем глобальную координату по "y" для курсора мыши. Для вычисления средней скорости запоминайте последние N смещений. Перед отпусканием посмотрите сумму смещений за последние N*30мс, затем разделите перемещение на время = получили среднюю скорость.
2. С помощью увеличения document.scrollTop на вычисленную скорость в единицу времени и постепенно снижая скорость до нуля добейтесь эффекта замедления.

N.B. при клике по скроллу снова при помощи clearInterval сбросьте анимацию.

Comment: по первому пункту крайне не согласен... зачем... берем координаты на mousedown, запоминаем время, берем координаты на mouseup, вычисляем расстояние(попифагору например) и скорость (и даже направление если надо)...

Comment: ага. Видел я такие приложения. Любые случайные движения(например, если между click/unclick очень мало времени прошло) - и страница улетает. Надо именно среднее считать, чтобы сглаживание было. N и временной интервал подбирается опытным путем.  
Аналогично: зажал курсор, провел немного вниз. Потом задумался(картинка красивая). Потом решил подкрутить побыстрее и отпустил. А вот фиг: прошло 10 секунд, скорость никакая.

Comment: @knes, а как средняя скорость изменится? Вы хотите выкинуть часть значений? У ТС, вроде, скрол такой: зажал - двинул - отпустил. Естественно, нельзя блокировать при сколе повторное такое действие. Т.е. если медленно - сделай еще раз. А-то контрпример - быстро двинул, затупил и отпустил через 10 секунд только.

Comment: Если быстро двинул, затупил, отпустил через 10(2 или 1) секунд(у), в моем случае оно никуда не поедет, что логично, так как средняя скорость за последние 3-4 интервала равна нулю: когда мы отпускаем неподвижный ползунок, мы не ожидаем, что оно поедет куда-то.

Comment: ну не знаю, все эти setInterval :) тогда-уж на mousemove и мерить. мне вообще нравится то как я делал, т.к. вообще не двигать картинку когда и мышь нажата и двигается, как-то странно (пример в другом вопросе этого-же ТС) подумал еще что можно части  считать в зависимости от того какое начальное значение координат было у мыши.

Comment: Как вариант, можно смотреть на "пройденный путь" курсора мыши с зажатой клавишей. То есть, мы измеряем скорость с самого начала, но вызываем функцию прокрутки после mouseup, только если путь был минимум, например, пикселей 100.

Comment: @Deonis, cправедливо. Это также убережет от случайных смещений. И тогда можно и правда не заморачиваться с мониторингом скорости, а сделать, как советует @eicto: "100" пикселей уже случайно не дернуть. Видимо, это и имелось в виду, тогда прошу прощения.

Comment: Во флеше ещё видел инерционное взаимодейстиве: делают невидимую цель, которую тащит мышь. А контент следует за этой целью: `Xc += k * (Xt - Xc)`. Коэф. регулирует от совсем ленивого и тормозного до почти живого протаскивания. 
Этот способ позволит  всегда иметь "последнюю" скорость, прежде, чем мыш потерялась или дёрнулась. И исходя из неё делать после-касание.